# jqplot show labels using date axis renderer

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, graph, charts, jqplot

i'm using jqplot 1.0.0b1_r746. i want to display some time periods using the date axis renderer. the chart looks like as follows:

[image: chart]
now i would like to show the begin and end date as labels of one period. i have tried to use the pointLables plugin, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the usage point lables labels was the right approch. the label is the last element of each point, e.g.

```
var line1=[['2008-06-30',1,'line1'], ['2008-7-30',1,'line1']];
```

then you have to use the point lables configuration, e.g.

```
pointLabels: {
    show: true
 }
},
```

see the docs for futher information: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pointLabels-js.html